# Change an image with "onmouseover"

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover

I'm trying to change an image src using JavaScript. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(a) {
    document.getElementById("img").src=a;
}
</script>

<div class="fill">
<img id="img" src="books\thumbnail\10.jpg\">
<img src='books\big\4.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("books\bigger\4.jpg");'>
<img src='books\big\5.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("books\bigger\5.jpg");'>
<img src='books\big\6.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("books\bigger\6.jpg");'>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using backslashes instead of forward slashes?

Comment: I think you need to put a `#` in front of the `img` in `document.getElementById("img").src=a;`.  Plus you don't have an id for each image so how's it going to know which image to change.

Comment: @evan.stoddard: The `#` is only need when using CSS style selectors in JavaScript. The image to change is the one with the ID `img`.

Comment: Oh ok.  I use jQuery a lot so I use hash tags and periods for selected specific elements.

Comment: try using forward slashes(/), instead of back slashes(\\). And you don't need the slash that follows "10.jpg".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(a) {
    document.getElementById("img").src=a;
}
</script>

<div class="fill">
<img id="img" src="books/thumbnail/10.jpg/">
<img src='books/big/4.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("books/bigger/4.jpg");'>
<img src='books/big/5.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("books/bigger/5.jpg");'>
<img src='books/big/6.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage("books/bigger/6.jpg");'>
</div>
```

Comment: could you use `this.src` in changeImage rather than repeating the url each time?

Comment: @Chimoo: No, because the `mouseover` elements are `books/big/...`, but the `src` being passed is `books/bigger/...`, as in thumbnail and full size. Though a `.replace()` could be done in the `changeImage()` function.

Comment: ah ok, but yes a replace would be better. the code in this answer then isn't doing what the OP wants as it stands, as it is passing the thumbnail not the bigger one

Comment: @Chimoo: The original was doing it correctly. The answer was modified temporarily to pass `this.src`, but then changed. The newest revision didn't correctly revert back to the original.

Comment: ...I rolled it back to the original since the answer was accepted.

Comment: I've added an answer for the replace version

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would've done it, makes it a bit more scalable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(img) {
    document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace("/big/", "/bigger/");
  }
</script>

<div class="fill">
  <img id="img" src="books/thumbnail/10.jpg">
  <img src='books/big/4.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage(this)'>
  <img src='books/big/5.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage(this)'>
  <img src='books/big/6.jpg'  onmouseover='changeImage(this)'>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById("img").src=a;
```

Finds element with ID "img". To find current image try

```
changeImage(this, "books\bigger\4.jpg");
```

And,

```
function changeImage(img, string)
{
    img.src = string;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try doing this in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("img").onmouseover=changeImage("http://placehold.it/500");
```

Worked for me.